# Probability of having a disorder using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability, self-learning, bayesian

$30$% of the country has a disorder. A blood test has developed that has a $90$% true positive rate(the probability that a person will test positive given that they have the disorder) and a $25$% false positive rate (the probability that a person will test positive given that they don't have the disorder). Every person who has tested positive uses medicine which has a $20$% rate of causing acne. What's the probability that someone has acne and actually have the disorder.

---

I know how to find probably of people who are actually ill given a positive rate. But I don't know how to use the acne rate to find the probability of ill people.

$P(D)$ = $30$%  the probability of having the disorder

$P(\bar{D})$ = $70$% probability of being healthy

If E stands for having acne and T+ for testing positive:

$P(E) = P(E|D,T+)\cdot P(D, T+) + P(E|\bar{D}, T+)\cdot P(\bar{D}, T+)$,

Comment: You've tagged the problem Bayesian.  Please edit your query to show your work, re using Bayes theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: The assumptions are unclear. Are the only people taking the medicine those that have tested positive, or are others also taking it? Is the only way to have acne as a side-effect of that one medicine? As long as we don't know that, it'll be hard to get an answer at all. Does everyone get a test, or just if you have symptoms?

Comment: only people who have tested positive are taking the medicine and the only way of having acne is the medicine.

Answer (score 1):

> only people who have tested positive are taking the medicine and the only way of having acne is the medicine.

Of course I agree with @Henno Brandsma but if this is the case, it is not necessary to know what's the rate of false positive (EDIT: they do not have the disorder thus they do not affect $D \cap A$)

thus the solution is simply

$P(T^+ \cap D)=0.3\times 0.9=0.27$

and $P(D\cap A)=0.27\times0.2=5.4\%$

Comment: 70% of people are healthy and the probability that a person will test positive given that they don't have the disorder is 25%. so they also use medicine

Comment: @shadi : yes I corrected my wording (my numbers are the same)